# adicionar acentos no gnuplot

Tags: plot

Como eu faço para colocar acentuação na legenda do eixo x e y do gnuplot? já tentei colocar a codificação ascii mas não funciona

```
# Rótulo do eixo x
set xlabel "Iteracoes" font "Helvetica,20"
```

preciso que a palavra fique "interações"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute o código antes de plotar:

```
set encoding utf8
```